# With nmap and awk, displaying any http ports with the host's ip

Tags: linux, nmap

I scanned around 50 hosts on a network with this command:

```
nmap -sV -iL sweep_ips.txt -oG result.txt  

ex: ...
Host: 192.168.x.x ()    Ports: 8000/open/tcp//http//Apache httpd 2.2.3 ((CentOS))/  Ignored State: filtered (999)
...
```

I display the ips of those with http ports found:

```
grep http result.txt | awk '/http/{print $2}'
```

So far, so good. Except that the http port is not always 80 or 443. I have some odd ones like 10000 and such. I would like awk to find the specific port field where it finds "http" and then display part or all of that field. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
192.168.x.x 8000
```

would be sufficient.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a pure `awk` question and not an nmap or an InfoSec question.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[1] $1" if m{([0-9]*)/open[^,]*/http}'
```

Tried to do this with awk, but it doesn't do captures. Instead, Perl's `-a` switch splits the line just like awk, with the substrings accessed through the `%F` hash. A better solution would account for multiple "http" services on a single host.